# int method returning wrong value

Tags: java, android

I'm sure my syntax is wrong somewhere...
I have the following method:

```
private int getVersionStatus(){
        // Creates instance of the manager.
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

        // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();


        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            versionCode=appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability();
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + String.valueOf(appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()));
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value123: " + String.valueOf(versionCode));     
        });

        return versionCode;        
    }
```

When I call the method from `onCreate()` both the logs print the correct value but the returned int (versionCode) is different...How is this so?

Comment: `return String.valueOf(versionCode);` ?

Comment: I need to return an `int`

Answer (score 3):

That is because `versionCode` is returned before `addOnSuccessListener` is called. The listener is set, `getVersionCode()` returns and eventually the lambda of `addOnSuccessListener` is called.

With the apis you have used now, returning a value is not possible. What you could do is pass a callback as an argument to `getVersionCode()`.

An example:

```
    interface Callback {
        void setVersion(int version);
    }

    private void getVersionStatus(Callback callback){
        // Creates instance of the manager.
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

        // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();


        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            callback.setVersion(appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability());
        });
    }

    private void yourOtherFuncton() {
        getVersionStatus(version -> {
            Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + String.valueOf(version));
        });
    }
```

It's basically them same as PPartisan' answer, with your own defined interface.

Comment: could you give an example

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, I'm assuming this is the section that retrieves your version code:

```
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    versionCode=appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability();
    //...
});
```

In which case, you're treating asynchronous code in a synchronous way. Without adding a dependency on another library (i.e., RxJava), you can get around this by changing your method signature to use a callback instead of returning a value:

```
private void versionCode(IntConsumer consumer) {
    //...
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        consumer.accept(appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability());
    });
}
```

With usage:

```
versionCode(code -> Log.d("TAG", "Version code is: " + code));
```

Comment: thanks, that approach requires minSDK of 24.. I need 21

Comment: That's probably because `IntConsumer` came in on Java 8 - you can just define your own callback for this (an `interface` that has a single method which takes in an `int` argument)